# How to bypass if data in a row exist in database?

Tags: php, mysql

My table contains id and group.

```
id        group
 1        alpha
 2        beta
 3        omega
```

My validation code is:

```
$validate_query = "SELECT * FROM table_test WHERE id = '{$id}' ";
                $rs = mysql_query($validate_query,$connection);
                if(mysql_num_rows($rs) != 0) {
                    echo "<span class='confirmation'>Oops! Data exist. Try another one.</span>";
                } 
                else { 

                    $query = "UPDATE table_test SET 
                            group= '{$group}'               
                            WHERE id = '{$id}'                      
                            ";
                    $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
```

but my goal is like this...

```
**example:**
if the user want to edit the field group value(ex. alpha) into (beta).. 
then the value of id 1 and 2 is beta...
```

now i want just to check if value is exist.. i just want to getback the original value (alpha) so that there is no duplicate....

Comment: USE MYSQLI NOT MYSQL. The function you are using is DEPRECATED!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well you just have to change your query to this -

```
$validate_query = "SELECT * FROM table_test WHERE group = '{$group}' ";
```

Comment: sir... what if the user still rename it into existing data in a table... then there is a duplication..

Comment: no it wont, if you look into the above query it will look up for the $group in the table which contains the text for group that user input.. so if it exists the query will generate and your if statement fire the condition of echoing the message not the else block for updating the table..

Comment: sir... my desire like this,,, lets say alpha is our fetch data... if alpha rename it into beta => then just putback in alpha; and if alpha rename into bravo => then rename into bravo...... because bravo is not exist in database

Comment: yes bee it will do exactly that it will not rename if the value already exists.. it will rename only if it doesn't exists.. did you tried that code??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86589/discussion-between-manoj-salvi-and-bee).

Comment: oh dear.. the only mistake you are making is closing of else block...just put this } just before the query for your other table not at the end..before this[$sql = "SELECT * FROM test_group_details WHERE group_id = '{$group_id}' "; ]

Answer (score 0):

Change your query string to this:

```
$validate_query = "SELECT * FROM table_test WHERE group = '{$group}' AND id != '{$id}'";
```

And if you want database operation in every case. than:

```
                $validate_query = "SELECT * FROM table_test WHERE group = '{$group}' AND id != '{$id}'";
                $rs = mysql_query($validate_query,$connection);
                if(mysql_num_rows($rs) != 0) {
                    $query = "UPDATE table_test SET 
                            group= group               
                            WHERE id = '{$id}'";


                } 
                else { 

                    $query = "UPDATE table_test SET 
                            group= '{$group}'               
                            WHERE id = '{$id}'";
                 }
                 $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
```

Comment: still wont on the logic sir

Comment: @Bee Do you want database operation in every case? Or just try to restrict duplication? You can restrict duplication from the above query. I've done this many time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `unique constraint` on your column GROUP
So the update will trigger an error when you'll try to update with duplicate value.

Other solution is to add and `exist` clause in your update statement.

ie:

```
UPDATE table_test 
   SET group= '{$group}'               
 WHERE id = '{$id}'
   AND NOT EXISTS ( select 1 
                      FROM table_test 
                     WHERE group= '{$group}'  )
```

Now the statement will not trigger error and you may have to check how many row are updated in order to determine if the group already existed.